# TinyMCE 6 execCommand 'mceInsertContent' removes <a href> from inserted content

Tags: javascript, plugins, tinymce, tinymce-6

My custom plugin for tinymce 6 inserts html content like so:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<div id="container"><a href="/"><div id="inner">hi</div></a></div>');
```

However, the inserted content ends up like:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<div id="container"><div id="inner">hi</div></div>');
```

What is happening?

Does it have anything to do with valid elements?

My config includes:

```
valid_elements: '+*[*]',
extended_valid_elements: 'a[href|target=_blank|class]'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default TinyMCE doesn't support block-based anchors, such as a `<div>` within an `<a>` tag. Explanation here: https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/3142#issuecomment-241976643

Possible workarounds:

Use an inline element like `<span>` instead of `<div>`

```
<div id="container"><a href="/"><span id="inner">hi</span></a></div>
```

Use `valid_children` to add the elements you want inside the anchor element. Here's a fiddle to demo how to do that: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/Lkiaab (Certain things may not work as expected, for example editing links via the link plugin.)

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!